# Delete data on database table using text area on PHP/HTML

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a problem regarding to deleting my data on my database table using text area,
I have a text area, inserting a data to database table
I input like

```
A
B
C
D
```

Then it will input on different column on database table.
Now I have A new code that I want to delete the data on the database column when I input the

```
A
B
C
D
```

on the text area.
but doesnt deleted.
When I input a format like A,B,C,D on the text area it delete the data on the database table. but i want it to like a format

```
A
B
C
D
```

This is my Code for deleting data.

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "wip";

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

// Check the connection
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

// Get the submitted data
$lines = $_POST['lines'] ?? '';

// Split the lines into an array using newline character
$linesArray = explode("\n", $lines);

// Prepare the SQL statement
$sql = "DELETE FROM wiptest WHERE line1 = ? AND line2 = ? AND line3 = ? AND line4 = ?";

// Prepare and bind the statement
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

if (!$stmt) {
    die("Prepare failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $line1, $line2, $line3, $line4);

foreach ($linesArray as $line) {
    $lineParts = explode(',', $line);
    $line1 = trim($lineParts[0] ?? '');
    $line2 = trim($lineParts[1] ?? '');
    $line3 = trim($lineParts[2] ?? '');
    $line4 = trim($lineParts[3] ?? '');

    echo "Input: $line1, $line2, $line3, $line4<br>"; // Add this line for debugging

    // Execute the statement to delete the data
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        die("Execute failed: " . $stmt->error);
    }
}

// Check if any rows were affected
if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
    echo "Data deleted successfully!";
} else {
    echo "No matching data found to delete.";
}

// Close the statement and connection
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();

header("Location: maincanonout.php");
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Just use `$linesArray = explode("\n", $lines);` to define your `$line1`, `$line2`, `$line3` and `$line4` instead of `$lineParts = explode(',', $line);`

Comment: Well firstly, what debugging have you done? Start with `var_dump($_POST);` to check the data is arriving in PHP in the format you expect. Then after that, what does `echo "Input: $line1, $line2, $line3, $line4<br>";` output? You didn't tell us.

Comment: P.S. To make your code more robust (unless you're on PHP 8.1 or above where this is already enabled by default), add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. That way you don't need to clutter your script with repetitive code to keep checking errors after every mysqli command. And you should never be echoing error data deliberately - it can easily reveal sensitive info to attackers by accident.

Comment: Can you show the table structure?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is deleting rows identified by 4 comma separated values, like the following:

```
A,B,C,D
E,F,G,H
I,J,K,L
```

Every identifier contains 4 string values occupying one line, and you may have many identifiers if you have many lines (3 in my example).

Now, if you want to place your identifier vertically (but why?), like this:

```
A
B
C
D
```

...then you need to modify your code like follows (removing `foreach` statement which is not needed anymore):

```php
$line1 = trim($linesArray[0] ?? '');
$line2 = trim($linesArray[1] ?? '');
$line3 = trim($linesArray[2] ?? '');
$line4 = trim($linesArray[3] ?? '');
$stmt->execute();
```